# How do I create an expression-based index using the instr() function?

Tags: sqlite

With Sqlite3, I am trying to do a query like:

select *
from data
where instr(filepath,'.txt') != 0

And I want to index this query to speed it up.

I tried to create an index like:

create index data_instr_filepath
on data(instr(filepath,'.txt'));

However, "explain query plan" still shows that I'm doing a table scan.

Is this doable in sqlite?  The examples I have found for doing expression-based indexes seems to be limited to the length function and multiplying two columns together.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Mike's answer, I refactored my query to not use inequalities and was able to create an index that hits it.  Below are my indexes that I ended up using:

```
create index data_instr_filepath_txt on data(instr(filepath,'.txt'));

create index data_instr_filepath_substr on data(substr(filepath,0,instr(filepath,'.')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that an index will likely not be used for an inequality as per :-

> Similarly, index columns will not normally be used (for indexing
>   purposes) if they are to the right of a column that is constrained
>   only by inequalities. [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

You are able to try forcing the use of an index by using **INDEXED BY**. However, this will not work in your situation because of the above flagging the index as not being usable. (the query will still work)

e.g.

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM data INDEXED BY data_instr_filepath
WHERE instr(filepath,'.txt') != 0
```

results in :-

> no query solution
>   Time: 0s

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I re-factored my query to not used inequality-based expressions, and I was able to create indexes that do get used.